# How to find any sub field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have a collection of documents that looks like that :

```
{
  "slug": {
    "fr-FR": "test-1",
    "nl-NL": "test-2",
    "en-US": "test-3"
  }
}
```

In my app I need to check if a slug is used by any documents (each slug have to be globally unique, not only in their locale).
At the moment I need to do a big request like this :

```
.findOne({
  $or: [ 
    { "slug.fr-FR": "test-1" },
    { "slug.nl-NL": "test-1" },
    { "slug.en-US": "test-1" }
  ]
})
```

So I was wondering if there's any solution to shorten this query using wildcards.

I hope this all makes senses to you !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript function() you can avoid individual match statements:

```
db.collection.find(function(){
    for ( var k in this.slug ) {
        if ( this.slug[k] == "test-1" )
            return true;
    }
})
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, however I was wondering if this was possible only using an object, but thank you for the answer

Comment: MongoDB has no Wildcard support in index/query. ie. you cannot do something like ```.findOne("slug.*" : "test-1") ``` https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267